# How to handle conditional reducer in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Consider a Todo List app, where the user can add **at most 5** tasks.

I am checking the store for current number of tasks and
dispatching an ADD action depending on that(i.e. if there's already 5 tasks, do not dispatch).

My question is should I also check this inside the reducer(i.e. do not add if there's already 5 tasks)?

Comment: Is adding a task an asynchronous operation? If so, then it seems feasible to dispatch two ADD actions before the state updates. If not, I'd venture to say that it's unnecessary to check it in your reducer. However, it doesn't seem like it would be a lot of overhead to check just in case.

Comment: I am concerned if I don't couple it with reducer logic then in future it might get hard to maintain. Because then I'll have to do this validation for any stub that will initiate a change in task list.

Comment: since the reducer is the last place you can check before updating the state, I guess a bit of logic there  won't hurt :) but it all depends on your application. So you can do something like this: https://github.com/arunoda/learn-redux/blob/dir-structure/src/reducers/index.js#L6

Comment: If you are able to *only* check it in your reducer, I don't see why you wouldn't.